Virus spreads through music file, threatens to destroy town
I remember seeing this movie a long time ago. It was about a computer virus some guy had made and disguised in an MP3 file or whatever the equivalent was back in the day. There was a guy who used a wheelchair, and several (unintentionally) hilarious scenes. There was one scene where somebody (in order to defeat the virus) somehow programmed an antivirus with nothing but a gameboy. Another scene was the programmer getting killed by his own virus while riding in a jet/plane (he realized he was going to die because the song decided to play over the intercom for whatever reason). Also, I think I remember the wheelchair guy having to sacrifice himself to stop the virus by using the gameboy virus or I don't even know. It's hard to explain. Oh, and there was a part where the virus got into the power grid and decided to start blowing things up by overpowering them.
In short, it was stupid, it sounds like it'd be hilarious to dig up and watch again today to make fun of with my friends.

The movie is:
Terminal Error (2002)
Plot:

"Elliot, an ex-employee of a computer firm wants revenge and befriends
  the boss Brad's son Dylan giving him an MP3 file containing a computer
  virus. This virus creates havoc all across the city by poisoning the
  water with chlorine, making planes crash and ultimately developing an
  intelligence of its own. The virus is eventually traced to a server
  and is terminated by another equally powerful virus created by Brad
  and Dylan with a Game Boy Color."
  - Wikipedia

Additional link:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0283542/
